# NGiNX Http Push Module - broadcast behaves random

Tags: php, nginx

The symptoms: I have the "push_listener_concurrency" set to "broadcast" but only several (random amount) of subscribers get the message. Was anybody dealing with this type of problem? The test cases are pretty straight-forward I 'POST' to a `'/publisher?cid=test'` channel and 'GET' from a `'/listener?cid=test'` everything seems to be working when there's only one client per channel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case somebody will face the same problem.

There were a problem with headers. To listen the nginx http push module correctly with jQuery you should use a listener that processes the headers correctly here is my code:

```
function Listener(url, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    var scope = this;
    var etag = 0, lastModified = 0;

    var launched = false;

    var failure = false;

    this.successTimeout = 0;
    this.failureTimeout = 5000;

    var getTimeout = function () {
        return failure ? this.failureTimeout : this.successTimeout;
    };

    var listen = function () {
        $.ajax(scope.ajaxOptions);
    }

    var beforeSend = function (jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("If-None-Match", etag);
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", lastModified);
    };

    var complete = function (jqXHR) {
        var timeout = getTimeout();

        etag = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Etag');
        lastModified = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified');

        var timeout = jqXHR.statusText == 'success' ? scope.successTimeout : scope.failureTimeout;

        if (timeout > 0) {
            setTimeout(listen, timeout);
        } else {
            listen();
        }
    };

    this.ajaxOptions = {
        url : url,
        type : 'GET',
        async : true,
        error : failureCallback,
        success : successCallback,
        dataType : 'json',
        complete : complete,
        beforeSend : beforeSend,
        timeout: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    };

    this.start = function (timeout) {
        if (!launched) {
            if (typeof(timeout) == 'undefined' || timeout == 0) {
                listen();
            } else {
                setTimeout(listen, timeout);
            }
            launched = true;
        }
    };
}
```